# HTML, Javascript, CSS text menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBPVk.jpg)I have made a text as a button and want to create a menu with that. What I am trying to do is to change the text. When I click the button, it works as a circular menu and shows me options.

For example, it was L(litter) = 1, when I click the button it shows me other parameters such as mL, gallon, ounce. If I click mL, the text will change from L = 1000 to mL = 1000.

Could you help with me actual coding if possible? This is what I currently have. When I click, I can type a value and it changes the value. I don't need to type the value but it should display one of the values I already stored in depending on what I click on the menu.

```
var para = document.querySelector('button');
para.addEventListener('click', updateValue);
function updateValue() {
  var value = prompt('Enter a new value');
  para.textContent = value;
}
```

Comment: Basically: you want a <select> component (but without using the <select> tag so you can style it as you please), yes?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `<select>`?

Answer (score 1):

If I get you clear so this example is what you need

```css
body {
  font-family: Alegreya Sans;
  background: #feeded;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  background: #cd3e3d;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 5em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1em solid #fdaead;
}

.menu:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 0.2em;
  border-top: 0.6em double #fff;
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid #fff;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  width: 5em;
  height: 1.4em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
  transition: all 1s;
  background: #fdaead;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.menu:hover li {
  opacity: 1;
}


/**
 * Add a pseudo element to cover the space
 * between the links. This is so the menu
 * does not lose :hover focus and disappear
 */

.menu:hover ul::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  top: -5.0em;
  /**
   * The pseudo-element is a semi-circle
   * created with CSS. Top, bottom, and right
   * borders are 6.5em (left being 0), and then
   * a border-radius is added to the two corners
   * on the right.
   */
  border-width: 6.5em;
  border-radius: 0 7.5em 7.5em 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  /**
   * Have to have a border color for the border
   * to be hoverable. I'm using a very light one
   * so that it looks invisible.
   */
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  /**
   * Put the psuedo-element behind the links
   * (So they can be clicked on)
   */
  z-index: -1;
  /**
   * Make the cursor default so it looks like
   * nothing is there
   */
  cursor: default;
}

.menu a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  /**
   * This is to vertically center the text on the
   * little tab-like things that the text is on.
   */
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.menu a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-2em);
  transition: 1s all;
}

.menu:hover ul {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-1em);
}

.menu li:hover {
  background: #cd3e3d;
  z-index: 10;
}

.menu li:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.2em;
  top: -4.2em;
}

.menu li:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 2em;
  top: -3em;
}

.menu li:nth-of-type(3) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3.4em;
  top: 0.3em;
}

.menu li:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 2em;
  top: 3.7em;
}

.menu li:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.2em;
  top: 5em;
}

.hint {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will try testing. Can I ask if I get another question after testing it? Have a great night :)

Comment: How can I change the position of the menu? I mean how can I make the text as a menu? It looks like a text but if I click it it works as the menu you gave. I just uploaded a picture to help your understanding.

Comment: Oh I am terribly sorry for making you to misunderstand... If you see the uploaded image, you will see that d=-0.32 is in green and I made it as a button. I wonder how I can make that d=-0.32 work as a menu u made. So, if I click that d=-0.32, it expands as a circular menu (as u did before) and if I click one of them (instead of products, services, and others) will change the text from d=-0.32 to a = 1.23 for example.